# Having trouble with my code on searching for an element of an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, find, element

I've been struggling with this bit of code for a while, I can't seem to find out where I'm going wrong. Basically I want to search through an Array using an Integer and if it matches an element inside that array, it returns a bool variant as true. It's quite self explanatory but can't for the life of me figure it out! Any ideas?

Here is the code;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ArrayProject
{
    class ArrayProgram
    {
        public bool ElementAt(int[] intArray, int valueToBeFound)
        {
            bool intAt = false;
            int numberTofind;

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number you wish to search for within the array: ");
            numberTofind = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            foreach (int x in intArray)
            {
                if (x == numberTofind)
                {
                    intAt = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    intAt = false;
                }
            }
            if (intAt == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is in the array!", numberTofind);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the array.", numberTofind);
            }

            return intAt;
        }
        public void RunProgram()
        {
            int[] intArray = { 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10 };
            int numberTofind = 0;

            ElementAt(intArray, numberTofind);

        }  // end RunProgram()

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ArrayProgram myArrayProgram = new ArrayProgram();
            myArrayProgram.RunProgram();

            Console.WriteLine("\n\n===============================");
            Console.WriteLine("ArrayProgram: Press any key to finish");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does your code return?  what are you expecting to happen?
I might suggest exiting the loop if you find your number....

Comment: What William Suggests is correct. I don't think you're getting the right return value because the foreach loop is continuing instead of either returning or breaking out of your loop. There's also the Contains and IndexOf that Dmitriy mentioned which will do this computation for you.

Comment: Use a List<int> instead of an array.  List has more functionality :             List<int> intArray = new List<int>() { 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10 };
            int index = intArray.IndexOf(60);

Comment: I'm pretty new at programming, I didn't realise that a foreach loop would be infinite? I thought it only cycled once. Still got lots to learn lol.
     
Edit: Thanks for the replies! The reason I haven't used any of those methods or a list<> is because the person who gave us the examples told us we could do it without them.

Answer (score 1):

```
        int[] intArray = { 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10 };
        int numberToFind = 0;

        //variant 1 (using System.Linq):
        bool bInside1 = intArray.Contains(numberToFind);

        //variant2
        bool bInside2 = Array.IndexOf(intArray, numberToFind) >= 0;
```

And if you want to write your own function:

```
    bool IsInside(int[] arrToSearch, int nToSearch)
    {
        foreach (int n in arrToSearch)
        {
            if (n == nToSearch)
                return true;
        }
        return false; //not found
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Trying them now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your loop continues checking elements and updating `intAt` even if it finds the element you're looking for.

If the array was `{1, 2, 3, 4}` and your code was searching for `1`, it would first check index `0`. This is a match, so `intAt` becomes `true`. Next it will try index `1`. This one isn't a match, so it sets `intAt` to be false. Then it will try indices `2`, `3`, etc. never finding the match.

Comment: Ooh! That makes a lot of sense actually, so I could add a break; to the code if it finds the element?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this pretty easy with Linq.

```
using System.Linq;

public static string test(int[] numberArray, int find) 
{ 
            bool s = false;
            numberArray.ToList().ForEach(x => { if (x == find) s = true; }); 
            return s ? "It contains it." : "Can't find it.";
}
```

However there is a method for this. You can use .Contains with an array as a person said above me.

Comment: > numberArray.ToList().ForEach(x => { if (x == find) s = true; });

The way that is written, is that like a short hand for programming? All I've been taught is the long hand versions.

Comment: Its a linq method. Basically a compressed syntax. Its the same as a foreach loop though. No performance boosts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your implementation, try this:

```
class ArrayProgram
{
    public bool ElementAt(int[] intArray, int valueToBeFound)
    {
        foreach (int x in intArray)     
            if (x == valueToBeFound)        // if you found your value in the array
                return true;                // you return true

        return false;   // otherwise, by this point the foreach has looped through all the elements and hasn't once entered in the above if (so it hasn't found your value) = you return false
    }

    public void RunProgram()
    {
        int[] intArray = { 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10,99 };
        int numberTofind;

        // I noticed that you're not using the numberTofind value either, so:

        Console.Write("Please enter the number you wish to search for within the array: ");
        numberTofind = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        // and since you made a function that returns true if your value has been found, you might as well use it like this

        if(ElementAt(intArray, numberTofind)) // if the function returns true
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is in the array!", numberTofind);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the array.", numberTofind);
    }  // end RunProgram()

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayProgram myArrayProgram = new ArrayProgram();
        myArrayProgram.RunProgram();

        Console.WriteLine("\n\n===============================");
        Console.WriteLine("ArrayProgram: Press any key to finish");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This made it a bit more clear, as I could use my existing code. I can see where I went wrong with it :)